# ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' in pycharm

Tags: python, random, pycharm

I write a simple python in pycharm:

```
import requests

req = requests.get("http://phika.ir/")
print(req)

req = requests.get("https://phika.ir/python")
print(req)
```

but in result I came up with:

```
random
from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
```

as you see, I didn't use random function!

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the codebase of `requests`. Are you sure you're running the right file that only contains your first code block? Or is the second block the output of the first? I'm confused...

Comment: Does your module (file, or parent directory) by any chance has the name `random`?

Comment: Why are you showing code using the requests library when your question is about the random module?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem!!! I have saved a python file named *random.py* in current directory. so, I changed the name of this file and the problem solved.